Run a random single examble block of Scenario outline in cucumber
I have a java cucumber framework
I run tests through testNG.
All the tests cases written has to be executed for multiple test data.
So I have a scenario Outline with 8 different examples. And these different example blocks represents different states.
I have given tags for each example so that to run with one of the state when required.
Is it possible to choose a random example and run only one everytime.?
Scenario Outline: Test state variation 
Given logged in to App
Then I validated something 

@ex1
Examples:
|abc|

@ex2
Examples:
|xyz|

Above is an example of scenario and I need ro run one example randomly every time.

Not with TestNG, but if you use JUnit 5 with the cucumber-junit-platform-engine instead then you can use JUnit 5 Launcher API to discover tests. The discoverrd tests form a test plan and you can modify that test plan prior to execution.
